# How do I fix a corrupt folder on a usb drive

Tags: usb, file-corruption

I had a folder on my USB drive that isn't being recognized as a folder. Here's an image.

[image]

That's supposed to be a folder. I've searched up lots of things but can't come up with it.

Comment: What file system are you using ?

Comment: I'm using FAT32.